# I have Ubuntu 14.10 and it doesnt recognize my network controller

Tags: networking, wireless, 14.10, atheros

I am brand new to Ubuntu and trying to learn as i go with this stuff. I can get online via ethernet but i can't figure out how to get wifi working. My network controller is the qualcomm atheros 003e(rev 20). I have also gotten 168c:003e. Under system settings/ network all i see is wired connection and network proxy. From the research i have done it seems that alot of people are having this issue but i cant seem to find a solution. Sorry for the lack of information but i don't have any idea what i am doing yet. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Jeremy31: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04 Wireless not working: no network interface](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661424/ubuntu-14-04-wireless-not-working-no-network-interface)

Answer (score 1):

This device will see minimal support- basically be able to connect to unsecured networks  in kernel 4.0, I would suggest finding a different wifi card for now. I believe the card is the QCA6174 and the developers for ath10k are working on it but it might take some time for it to be fully supported

I think this is what made it into kernel 4.0 http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/commit/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k?id=d63955b33b3bee45d784ffdfafeb93076c765660 and you can watch the log in linux-next for new news
http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/next/linux-next.git/log/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k

Comment: Going through my "schmucks" answers that didn't get any upvotes...  So finally you got one!  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby Thanks, it is too bad these cards still aren't supported 100% in the newest kernels.  Some have got them to work according to this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1383184)